Stock turbocharger with intercooler looses power as boost increases
I have a '91 Mercury Capri xr2 with a stock turbo with an intercooler. When driving after it reaches operating temperature even at part throttle say, uphill, the boost increases, and the power diminishes to a point that it won't climb up a small incline. I am clueless why this started happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need to use this vehicle at this time.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
